# Checking if string is a date using mktime() in c

Tags: c, date

Is it possible to determine, if some string, for ex. `2015-10-19` is a date, **using mktime()**? I want to avoid strings like `2015-a2-19` or `a015x08-b9` etc. and I must avoid `ifs` or `switch`.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to avoid if and switch? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Because of HW statement at school. Unfortunately, I have no idea..

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a homework service. You are expected to do previous research on your own and provide examples of code you have tried.

Comment: [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime). But it's going to be pretty difficult to avoid the use of `if` since you'll need to check the return value to determine whether the string was parsed successfully no matter what library function you use.

Comment: Not using Ifs in c programming is like saying make a cake but dont use any form of flour or starch.

Comment: Well, if one wants to be a smart alec then one could avoid `if` by using `while` with an unconditional `break` in the body :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try scanning the string into a `struct tm`, and then calling `mktime` on that:

```
// returns 0 if not a valid date, !=0 otherwise
int isValidDate(const char *s)
{
     struct tm t = {};
     sscanf(s, "%d-%d-%d", &t.tm_year, &t.tm_month, &t.tm_day);
     return ((int)mktime(&t) + 1);
 }
```

`mktime` returns `-1` if it cannot be represented in `time_t`, so we add one to it to get a zero. No need to check the return value of `sscanf` as it will result in a failure of `mktime` anyway.

Note that this only tells you if the date is valid in the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (usually), so 1500-11-11 will be invalid, even though it is obviously a valid date.